# Can I access/download a text file that file_put_contents is writing to intermittently?

Tags: php, file, execution

I'm working on an S3 upload script that creates and writes to a log file during the process.  It writes using `file_put_contents()` with the `FILE_APPEND` flag.

What I'd like to be able to do, if possible, is be able to download a copy of that file during the process to see where it's at, particularly if the process seems to be taking longer than it should be.

I realize it may not be possible... but perhaps there's some clever way to get the current contents of that file by doing something in between the `file_put_contents()` calls in the script...?

Comment: then it may take even longer time in writing due to your new script

Comment: It's a matter of how the file is being accessed. When you open a file in most OS'es, there is a set of permissions you concede to other people. You may open it in a manner that only your process may write to it, but all other processes may read from it. That way, you can download it while it's being written, no problem, as long as the file exists (i.e.: you have at least a blank file in a directory). I'm not giving an answer because I don't know the specific way to do that in PHP, though.